# PostgreSQL - duplicate data show and count

Tags: postgresql

This is table.

```
CREATE TABLE cameras
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sq_streams'::regclass),
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  exid text NOT NULL,
  owner_id integer NOT NULL,
  is_public boolean NOT NULL,
  config json NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  last_polled_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  is_online boolean,
  timezone text,
  last_online_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  location geography(Point,4326),
  mac_address macaddr,
  model_id integer,
  discoverable boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  preview bytea,
  thumbnail_url text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_streams PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

that config object is of type json and containing json data inside it as well.

i have 5000 records in this. What i am trying to get is , 
There are 57 Cameras and they have everything different but 3 things are same. which are

```
'external_http_port', config->> 'external_host', config-> 'snapshots'->> 'jpg'
```

I want to create a query which will show me results as

```
external_http_port | external_host | config-> 'snapshots'->> 'jpg' | Count
"93.87.73.118"     | "1024"        |      "/oneshotimage.jpg"      | 57
"180.180.180.48"   |  "81"         |"/onvif/media_service/snapshot"|20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a simple `group by` query, using the 3 expressions that get data out of the json column:

```
select 
    config->>'external_http_port' as external_http_port, 
    config->>'external_host'      as external_host, 
    config->'snapshots'->>'jpg'   as jpg,
    count(*)                      as count
from
    cameras
group by 
    config->>'external_http_port',
    config->>'external_host', 
    config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' 
-- having                              -- to show only those 
--     count(*) > 1                    -- with count > 1
  ;
```

Tested in **[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/244d0/1)**.

Comment: it is showing count 1 as well, what if i just want all those whom have count more than 1?

Comment: add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`